# how to get the client name logging in website

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I had a website name

```
sampleWebsite:8080/SampleWebsite.jsf
```

and I want to get the client name/computer name of the one who access my website. I used this code to get the computer name every time accessing my website.

```
System.out.println(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName());
```

My computer name is `Lenovo-PC`.

Then I'm gonna access and log in to my website. I want the out output of my computername/client name which is `Lenove-PC`. But the output was `sampleWebsite` which is my server name. Can someone help me to get the clientname/computer name not the server name?

I appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The following will get you their IP address - i know you want their computer name but I'm not sure that's possible. Code is in VB.NET but you can convert to Java using online tools.

```
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Returns the Clients IP address
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns>
    ''' [String] The Clients IP address
    ''' </returns>
    ''' <remarks>
    ''' http://bytes.com/topic/asp-classic/answers/439176-how-get-clients-ip-address-asp-net
    ''' </remarks>
    Private ReadOnly Property ClientIPAddress() As String
        Get

            'Set default return value
            ClientIPAddress = "<unable to be determined>"

            Try
                Dim strClient_HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR As String = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR")
                Dim strClient_REMOTE_ADDR As String = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")

                'Check if the XFF header is present
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(strClient_HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR) Then

                    'Use the first entry in the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR list of IP addresses (comma separated)
                    '- the first entry is the Client IP address, the last entry is the last proxy IP address
                    Dim ipRange As String() = strClient_HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR.Split(","c)
                    ClientIPAddress = ipRange(0).Trim

                Else

                    'Use the REMOTE_ADDR value
                    ClientIPAddress = strClient_REMOTE_ADDR.Trim

                End If

            Catch ex As Exception
                'Return default value on exception

            End Try

        End Get
    End Property
```

Comment: This will be their public IP address.  Unless all his clients are on the same LAN this isn't possible without a binary installed on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible.  The best you're going to be able to do is log the IP.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can! I also do it in my application in my `springmvc` interceptor
and it is easy!

You need to have a request instance from passed from upper level.

```
(HttpServletRequest request)
request.getRemoteAddr();
request.getRemoteUser()
```

please exploit [JavaEE](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/), you could get from request instance method.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I able to get the Ip address of my computer. But using request.getRemoteUser() can get the computer name? Because when I used that code the output is null..

Comment: @steven_110791 no, `remoteUser` returns null only if browser did not fill this field, it is browser's action rather than a bug.

Comment: thanks rugal for big help. but do you have any idea or link how to solve this kind of problem? in case you already encountered this porblem.

Comment: @steven_110791 I think not. as I have said, it is browser's action from client, you could not force client browser to do what you want, different browser has different strategy in filling these fields. what I could recommend you is to check if these fields are null.

Comment: @steven_110791 Per the java doco, unless then user is "authenicated" that field will be null. Take a look on the web and you'll see that web sites indicate they track your IP address - not your computer name. Now it might be possible to get the computer name for internal users authenticated against your server - but tracking the IP address (per the code I provided, or using that JavaEE code) is your *best bet*.